# data-stretch True/false in kendo UI for Map and Chart in same View

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

We are Using kendo UI for IOS application.

I have a problem in `data-stretch`.

I have one `data-role="view" with data-stretch="true"`.

In that view I have 2 `DIV` tag,

1st Div with `id="googleMap"` which display Google Map

2nd Div with `id="dashboard"` which displays 2 chart and 2 tabular format data.

If I use `data-stretch="true"` then Dashboard `DIV` cannot show the default scroll because height of data is bigger then Apple tablet.

If I use `data-stretch="false"` then problem creates in googleMap DIV and it could not display Google Map.

My code is:

```
<div id="divmap" data-role="view" data-title="Expenditures" data-layout="Operationlayout" data-before-show="cleanview" data-show="OperationMenuList" data-stretch="false" data-init="ChartLoading">
   <div id="googleMap">
   </div>           
   <div id="dashboard">
       <div id="Fleet">
          <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">....</table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve my problem of `data-stretch`?

I have used like below to set value of data-stretch form java script,

```
var view = $("#divmap").data("kendoMobileView");
view.stretch = false;
```

But it is not working.

How can I set `data-stretch true/false` dynamically from javascript?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mobile view stretch configuration option cannot be set runtime (after the view is initialized), as a touch scroller widget is initialized depending on its value. You may consider instantiating a [touch scroller](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/scroller/index.html#/) on the dashboard div, while keeping the data-stretch view option set to true. Something like this:

```
<div id="dashboard" data-role="scroller" height="100%">
   <div id="Fleet">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">....</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem is when i rotate IPAD at that time when content is more then size of IPAD then it cant scroll after rotate. so for that what would be the solution?

Comment: Not sure what goes on in your case. Touch scroller (and mobile views in general) respond to device rotation reliably (see demo above for reference). Perhaps an outer element does not update its size correctly. You can post a jsbin or jsfiddle - I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks, i will pos in jsbin on monday and give u link for that.
in my case, it take height but scroll is not working after rotating IPAD. that is the last point is remains to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can set attributes on tags with JQuery...

JQuery:

```
$("#divmap").attr("data-stretch","true");
```

Keep in mind that "data-stretch" is a single attribute OF THE DIV, not the data source.

Comment: You may need to call init() on the div after you change values - it only reads those during the init.

Comment: You means is i have to call ChartLoading() function from data-init="ChartLoading", 
CharLoading() function works on Dashboard Div tag.

Comment: Well, you made that comment ten hours ago, have you tried both of your ideas yet? It's got to be one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I just used the following attribute in my 'view' which contains a div for map and one other div for something else.

```
data-use-native-scrolling="true"
```

It Solved my problem

Comment: in this case your whole app needs to use native scrolling

Comment: There is no central way to apply it on all of your data-role="view". You must manually add it to the view containing map div